# Play framework test mode error

Tags: java, playframework

I'm having a little problem with command "play test" or "play auto-test"...The first command gives me something like this:

```
My-heaven:jobboard Droid$ play test
~        _            _ 
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/   
~
~ play! 1.2.3, http://www.playframework.org
~ framework ID is test
~
~ Running in test mode
~ Ctrl+C to stop
~ 
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
23:07:33,827 INFO  ~ Starting /Users/Droid/Downloads/play-1.2.3/play-1.2.3/samples-and-tests/jobboard
23:07:33,832 WARN  ~ Declaring modules in application.conf is deprecated. Use dependencies.yml instead (module.crud)
23:07:33,833 INFO  ~ Module crud is available (/Users/Droid/Downloads/play-1.2.3/play-1.2.3/modules/crud)
23:07:34,858 WARN  ~ You're running Play! in DEV mode
23:07:35,020 INFO  ~ Listening for HTTP on port 9000 (Waiting a first request to start) ...
```

And http://localhost:9000/@tests shows me, that the route wan't found. After "play auto-test", the output looks like this:

```
My-heaven:jobboard Droid$ play auto-test
~        _            _ 
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/   
~
~ play! 1.2.3, http://www.playframework.org
~ framework ID is test
~
~ Running in test mode
~ Ctrl+C to stop
~ 
~ Deleting /Users/Droid/Downloads/play-1.2.3/play-1.2.3/samples-and-tests/jobboard/tmp
~
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
23:09:29,670 INFO  ~ Starting /Users/Droid/Downloads/play-1.2.3/play-1.2.3/samples-and-tests/jobboard
23:09:29,678 WARN  ~ Declaring modules in application.conf is deprecated. Use dependencies.yml instead (module.crud)
23:09:29,679 INFO  ~ Module crud is available (/Users/Droid/Downloads/play-1.2.3/play-1.2.3/modules/crud)
23:09:30,913 WARN  ~ You're running Play! in DEV mode
23:09:31,077 INFO  ~ Listening for HTTP on port 9000 (Waiting a first request to start) ...
~
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/modules/testrunner/FirePhoque
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.modules.testrunner.FirePhoque
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
~
```

What is wrong with that?

Comment: try copying the sample project outside of play installation and then running the test.

Comment: Solved by using version from github

Comment: You should post your solution as an actual answer(which you can accept later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - Download and build current version from Github.